# How to put heterogeneous types into a Rust structure

Tags: rust

My questions is two parts (since I couldn't get the first part, I moved to the second part, which still left me with questions)

Part #1: How do you insert heterogeneous `struct` types into a `HashMap`? At first I thought to do it via an `enum`

E.g.,

```
enum SomeEnum {
    TypeA,
    TypeB,
    TypeC,
}

struct TypeA{}
struct TypeB{}
struct TypeC{}

let hm = HashMap::new();
hm.insert("foo".to_string(), SomeEnum::TypeA);
hm.insert("bar".to_string(), SomeEnum::TypeB);
hm.insert("zoo".to_string(), SomeEnum::TypeC);
```

But I get a `"Expected type: TypeA, found type TypeB"` error

Part #2: So then I went to the docs and read up on [Using Trait Objects that Allow for Values of Different Types](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/second-edition/ch17-02-trait-objects.html), and simplified the problem down to just trying to put heterogeneous types into a `Vec`. So I followed the tutorial *exactly*, but I'm still getting the same type of error (in the case of the docs, the error is now `"Expected type SelectBox, found type Button"`.

I know static typing is huge part of Rust, but can anyone tell me/show me/refer me to any info related to putting different `struct` types in either a `Vec` or `HashMap`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rust won't do any mapping of types to enum variants for you - you need to explicitly include the data in the enum itself:

```
use std::collections::HashMap;

enum SomeEnum {
    A(TypeA),
    B(TypeB),
    C(TypeC),
}

struct TypeA {}
struct TypeB {}
struct TypeC {}

fn main() {
    let mut hm = HashMap::new();
    hm.insert("foo".to_string(), SomeEnum::A(TypeA {}));
    hm.insert("bar".to_string(), SomeEnum::B(TypeB {}));
    hm.insert("zoo".to_string(), SomeEnum::C(TypeC {}));
}
```

That said, if the *only* context in which you'll need to use those struct types is when you're using that enum, you can combine them like so:

```
use std::collections::HashMap;

enum SomeEnum {
    A {},
    B {},
    C {},
}

fn main() {
    let mut hm = HashMap::new();
    hm.insert("foo".to_string(), SomeEnum::A {});
    hm.insert("bar".to_string(), SomeEnum::B {});
    hm.insert("zoo".to_string(), SomeEnum::C {});
}
```

Comment: "Rust won't do any mapping of struct names to enum variants for you - you need to explicitly include the data in the enum itself:" no ?

Comment: @Stargateur: Elaborate? To me, the question sounded like they were trying to insert three different types into a hash map, which would require them to either use trait objects or wrap their three types in a single enum (the latter being what I showed in my answer). Maybe "Rust won't do any mapping of *types* to enum variants for you" would be a better way to phrase what I was saying, though.

Comment: Well, https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=e8974a51ee3d664bebc734345e0484cc&version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015 work fine... someenum is the common type

Comment: @Stargateur: None of the structs are being used, though (see the compiler warnings). There's no actual relationship defined between the enum variant `SomeEnum::TypeA` and the struct `TypeA`, they just have the same name.

Comment: Oh sorry, I was completely off

Comment: @Stargateur: No problem, just wanted to make sure I wasn't missing something :)